# Align Font Awesome icons (fa-2x) with stacked icons (fa-stack)

Tags: css, alignment, font-awesome

I'm trying to align 4 icons in a row for the share functionality of a website. When I was using 4 normal icons they aligned perfectly and were the same size. Now I'm trying to have one of them stacked so that it has a border and it's creating some problems

Below is code I've been playing with:

```
<div class="share-results">
  <a class="fa fa-2x fa-envelope-o" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Share by Email" data-placement="top" href="#"></a>
  <a class="fa fa-2x fa-facebook-square" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Share on Facebook" data-placement="top" href=""></a>
  <a class="fa fa-2x fa-twitter-square" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Share on Twitter" data-placement="top" href=""></a>
  <a class="fa fa-2x fa-stack" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Share by Link" data-placement="top" href="#">
    <i class="fa fa-square-o fa-stack-2x"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-link fa-stack-1x"></i>
  </a>
</div>
```

This creates:

[image: alignment with 2x]

It seems like there's just a sizing problem, so I played around with using fa-lg:

[image: alignment with lg]

And also without any sizing helper on the stacked element:

[image: alignment without helper]

Does anyone know how to align an icon with `fa-2x` to a stacked icons?

Comment: couldn't you explicitly set the width, height, and margins for the `.fa-stack` in your CSS?

Comment: @MannfromReno that seems like a possible solution (I'm trying it now), but I'd like a cleaner solution that would possibly be reusable and more stable.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is a way to accomplish this task with minimum usage of new CSS styles:

We should use envelope which has the same style as twitter and facebook, I mean square-style with `fa-envelope-square` class. And make all anchor items stacked:

```
<div class="share-results">
    <a class="fa-stack fa-1x" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Share by Email" data-placement="top" href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-envelope-square fa-stack-2x"></i>
    </a>
    <a class="fa-stack fa-1x" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Share on Facebook" data-placement="top" href="">
        <i class="fa fa-facebook-square fa-stack-2x"></i>
    </a>
    <a class="fa-stack fa-1x" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Share on Twitter" data-placement="top" href="">
        <i class="fa fa-twitter-square fa-stack-2x"></i>
    </a>
    <a class="fa-stack fa-1x" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Share by Link" data-placement="top" href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-square fa-stack-2x"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-inverse fa-link fa-stack-1x"></i>
    </a>
</div>
```

In addition to this we change margin between stacked elements to make them look as in your example:

```
.fa-stack { margin: -2px; }
```

The result would look like this:

[image: Icons set]

[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ivangrs/v4zLLkxg/)

Answer (score 6):

I couldn't figure out a durable solution using the fa-* classes alone, but I did come up with a couple of ways to accomplish this that are admittedly slightly hacky, but not terribly hacky.

The first approach superimposes the `fa-link` icon, as text, over a normal `fa fa-2x fa-square-o` icon.

```
<div class="share-results">
  <a class="fa fa-2x fa-envelope-o" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Share by Email" data-placement="top"></a>
  <a class="fa fa-2x fa-facebook-square" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Share on Facebook" data-placement="top"></a>
  <a class="fa fa-2x fa-twitter-square" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Share on Twitter" data-placement="top"></a>
  <a class="fa fa-2x fa-square-o stacked" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Share by Link" data-placement="top"></a>
</div>

<style>
    .stacked {
        position:relative;
    }   
    .stacked:after {
        position: absolute;
        font-family: FontAwesome;
        font-size: .6em;
        top:6px;
        left:4px;
        content: "\f0c1"; /*link icon*/
    }
</style>
```

The second approach uses a combination of `position: fixed` and a custom `font-size` to help the new link align slightly better:

```
<div class="share-results">
  <a class="fa fa-2x fa-envelope-o" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Share by Email" data-placement="top"></a>
  <a class="fa fa-2x fa-facebook-square" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Share on Facebook" data-placement="top"></a>
  <a class="fa fa-2x fa-twitter-square" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Share on Twitter" data-placement="top"></a>
  <a class="fa fa-2x fa-stack stacked2" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Share by Link" data-placement="top">
    <i class="fa fa-square-o fa-stack-2x"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-link fa-stack-1x"></i>
  </a>
</div>

<style>
    .stacked2 {
      position: fixed;
      font-size: 1.1em !important;
      top: -7px;
      left: -4px;
    }
</style>
```

The second approach is a little more accurate, but I've included the first for completeness if you'd like to play around with it.  Here are the end results, respectively:

[image]

And here's a [CodePen example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ogowwQ).

I'm not sure if this answers your question, but I hope this helps a little.

Answer (score 3):

Since the font awesome icons are all about widths, heights and line heights I tried to create a solution where all their values were the same to (hopefully) avoid confusion and to make it easier to update moving forward.

Using the example you gave I set these CSS properties:

```
.fa {
    /*this sets values for all icons*/
    color: gray;
    font-size: 50px;
    line-height: 55px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.fa-link {
    /*make inner icon smaller but keep line-height the same so its centered vertically*/
    font-size: 30px;
}
.fa-stack-cust {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 55px;
}
```

I wrapped the icons within a  un-ordered list and the are now showing all on the same line. [Here is the JS.Fiddle showing you a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/t1js1xcu/). You will be able to see the HTML changes even though they are minor. Hope that helps.